# Unable to get developer license for windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

When I try to create a windows store program in Visual Studio 2012, I was prompt to install the developer license, but VS2012 failed to get the license all the time, please see the picture below.
[image]

I closed this dialog and try it againd from Project-Store-Acquire Developer License, but still get the same error. 
I google this for a while and found a page on MSDN said there is a command mode, I try that, get the same error, see below picture.
[image]

I upgrade my Windows 8 from Windows 7 several days ago, and it was actived.
[image]

I didn't use any proxy for my internet connection, I can not build my windows store prgram without the license. any work around for this?

Comment: Is your Win8 activated? I had problems when I hadn't done that.

Comment: Yes, I upgrade it from Windows 7.

Comment: maybe try reinstalling your developer tools/VS?

Comment: I use the 90 days evaluation version Visual Studio, is that matters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the above works, I refresh my Windows 8 again. it works now.

Comment: what do you mean by "refresh my window"

Comment: Settings - Change PC Settings - General - Refresh your PC settings without affecting your files.

Comment: *WARNING* Refreshing your PC settings will uninstall all your apps.

Answer (score 2):

Run `Command Prompt` as `administrator`. If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the `password` or provide confirmation. Type `netsh winhttp reset proxy`  at the command prompt, and press `Enter`. Try to get `licence` again.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I have just installed Windows updates and now everything is working.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the “Edit Group Policy” Management Editor
2. Click to expand Computer Configuration, Administrative Templates, Windows Components, and then App Package Deployment.
3. Double-click the Allow development of Windows Store apps without installing a developer license setting.
4. In the Allow development of Windows Store apps without installing a developer license window, click Enabled and then click OK.
5. Double-click the Allow all trusted apps to install setting.
6. In the Allow all trusted apps to install window, click Enabled and then click OK.
    
   Setting the Group Policy to allow development of Windows Store apps without installing a developer license updates the following registry setting: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Appx\AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense = 1
    
   Setting the Group Policy to allow trusted applications updates the following registry setting: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Micros      oft\Windows\Appx\AllowAllTrustedApps = 1

If you are still facing same problem Then follow below steps:
 
1. Open following link and download Hotfix
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2871280
 
2. Install Hotfix and restart machine. 
                                                    -

Another alternative:
 
    • Start the Fiddler on the system and then try to get the Window Developer License

Comment: The Fiddler solution worked for me --->https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=egjIlwz2AmI

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to Task Scheduler corruption during the upgrade process
A hotfix was published by Microsoft, which resolves the issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2687198

If applying the hotfix does not work, try the following:

1. Create a new temporary user.
2. Switch to the new temporary user. (Go to Start screen, click on your name/avatar, click on new username in drop down box, and enter password.)
3. As the new user, open Visual Studio 11.
4. Create a new Metro project. When asked to acquire a new license, log in with your Microsoft Account.
5. Log off and switch back to my normal user account.
6. Open Visual Studio and your try running your Metro project.
7. Disable the temporary user. (it might be needed again when the license expires.)

Comment: This fix works for upgrading Windows 7 to Windows 8 Consumer Preview, but I used Windows 8 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and nothing I found on the web would help. The nice guy at MSDN Developer Hotline pointed out to me, that the system date and time must be set to the correct local time. That finally solved the problem and I was now able to activate a developer license.

If I understood him right, this is due to some SSL connection that failes if the time settings on both participants differ too much.

Comment: My system time was correctly set to the local time, and I sync it several times already, but, still cannot get the license. how did you connenct the MS hotline? I want a try.

Comment: @zzd: I simply googled for "MSDN contact" and found [this side](http://www.microsoft.com/germany/msdn/hotline/default.aspx) as first result. I wrote an email with my problem and someone of the service team actually called me back and helped me find the problem. To be honestly: I never experienced such a good service :)

Answer (score 0):

I have started Windows 8 Apps development. Visual Studio is my development tool. In middle I couldnot find a way to Get a license as Developer for Windows 8. Searched Google and found a cool descriptive way to how to get a developer License of Windows 8
  See here [How to get a Developer License for Windows 8 and Renew your old one soon.](http://dothisbest.com/how-to/get-a-developer-license-for-windows-8/)

Answer (score 0):

Run Command Prompt as administrator.Type

> netsh winhttp reset proxy

at the command prompt, and press Enter. Try to get licence again.
It worked for me.